# how to find the character of the representation $\rho$ for $X$

Tags: abstract-algebra

let   $G=D_{8}=<a,b: a^{4}=b^{2}=1 , b^{-1}ab=a^{-1}>$

$\rho:G\rightarrow GL(2,\mathbb{C}) $  is a representation   such that 
$a\rho=\begin{pmatrix}
  0 
& 1 \\
  -1 & 0 
\end{pmatrix}$           ,$b\rho=\begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 0 \\
  0 & -1 
\end{pmatrix}$   and $\chi$  is the character of this representation.
and $A=\{I_{G},\phi_{a^{2}}\}$ and  $X=G/A$

how to find the character  of the representation $\rho$ for $X$

Comment: What is $\phi$? And what did you try? You have everything explicitly given, so you just need to apply the definitions.

Comment: $\phi $ is a automorphism

Comment: Which one? And how do you define the quotient of a group by a group of automorphisms?